# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError while running a Python script with Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I'm new to Spark and PySpark. I'm trying to run a Python script to read data from a MySql database, as the following code shows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


sc = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

def mysql_connection():

    sql = SQLContext(sc)

    dataframe = sql.read.format("jdbc").options(
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/evidencia",
        driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
        dbtable="estados",
        user="root",
        password="").load()

    output = dataframe.collect()

    print ("_____________ OUTPUT _____________")
    print (output)

mysql_connection()
```

The loading part is okay, but when it comes to run the `collect()`, or any other, method on the dataframe, the following error is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/gustavo/Documentos/TCC/prototipo/connections/MysqlConnection.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       mysql_connection()   File "/home/gustavo/Documentos/TCC/prototipo/connections/MysqlConnection.py",
>   line 22, in mysql_connection
>       output = dataframe.collect()   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py",
>   line 466, in collect   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1257, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line
>   63, in deco   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 328, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o51.collectToPython. :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
>     at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3200)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3197)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3197)  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

I've searched for this error, but I couldn't find a solution for it.

I'm using a Anaconda virtual environment, with Python 3.6.6 and Spark 2.3.2

I use the following command to run the script (using Ubuntu 18.04 BTW):

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar ~/Documentos/TCC/prototipo/connections/MysqlConnection.py
```

If there are any more information needed to understand the problem, please, ask me:

Thanks.

Comment: Just by switching to Java 8 I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently, the Java version was causing the problem.

I was using openjdk-11.0.2 and switched to java oracle 8, and the script ran just fine.

Comment: How did you switch to java 8?