Save Dataframes as table using pytest
I am new to pytest and trying to test a Pyspark code which reads a parquet file, converts a double type to decimal type and appends the data to the table. My test case is failing when I try to execute df.write.mode.append('append').saveAsTable("tablename").
Could someone please tell me what I am missing here?
pytest.py file:
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def sample_df(spark):
    data = [(1,2.0, 12,'Test')]
    schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("foo1", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("foo2", DoubleType(), True),
            StructField("foo3", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("Name", StringType(), True)
        ]
    )
    sample_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    sample_df.createOrReplaceTempView("dummy_table")
    return sample_df

@pytest.mark.parametrize('dbutils', [run_params], indirect=['dbutils'])
def test_loadDataIntoForecastTable( spark_mock, dbutils,sample_df):
    spark_mock.read.parquet.return_value = sample_df
    loadDataIntoForecastTable(spark_mock,"test","test","test")
    spark_mock.sql.assert_called()

main class:
def loadDataIntoForecastTable(spark,bar1,bar2, s3_file_name):
    df = spark.read.parquet(s3_file_name)

    for dtype in df.dtypes:
        if(dtype[1] == 'double'):
            column = dtype[0]
            df = df.withColumn(column,df[column].cast("decimal(38,9)"))


    #delete existing data from the table
    df.select("foo1").distinct().createOrReplaceTempView("tempTableDeleteExisting")

    delete_query = """DELETE 
                      FROM {} fha
                      WHERE ID in (SELECT foo1 from tempTableDeleteExisting)"""


    delete_sql =  delete_query.format(bar2)
    print("the delete sql is : ",delete_sql)
    spark.sql(delete_sql)

    #update table
    df.write.mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").saveAsTable(bar2)

This is the stacktrace from my pytest file:

test_loadDataIntoForecastTable[dbutils0] -
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
o159.saveAsTable.

could someone please help?
Stack Trace:
> answer = 'xro160', gateway_client = <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient
> object at 0x00000279B6566260>, target_id = 'o159', name =
> 'saveAsTable'
> 
>     def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
>         """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.
> 
>         For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
>         integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
>         instances, etc.
> 
>         :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
>         :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
>             Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
>             list, map)
>         :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
>             (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
>         :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
>             (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
>         """
>         if is_error(answer)[0]:
>             if len(answer) > 1:
>                 type = answer[1]
>                 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
>                 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> >                   raise Py4JJavaError(
>                         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>                         format(target_id, ".", name), value) E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o159.saveAsTable. E                   :
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
> E                       at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
> E                       at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
> E                       at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249) E           
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454) E           
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
> E                       at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972) E    
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014) E 
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.validateTableLocation(SessionCatalog.scala:413)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:176)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:84)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:107)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900) E
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:107)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:461)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:461)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:437)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:98)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:859)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:700)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:678)
> E                       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:571)
> E                       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) E                       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> E                       at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> E                       at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) E          
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) E     
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
> E                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) E    
> at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) E
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) E           
> at
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> E                       at
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106) E    
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> 
> C:\JPMC\DEV\TMP\ds\tools\python3.10\latest\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326:
> Py4JJavaError


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805571/py4j-protocol-py4jjavaerror-while-running-a-python-script-with-pyspark

"1.8.0_411" - @pvy4917 I tried with this, still the same error

Try to mock spark.sql as well using something like spark_mock.sql.return_value = None and maybe do the same for the saveAsTable and the write methods. Also please paste the full stack trace of the error message - currently, it is not specifying the cause of the error.

what is fact_horizon_finance_analytics? I don't see it in code.

Solved: CDH 6.2 Spark 2.4.0 saveAsTable error: java.io.IO... - Cloudera Community - 297041

@furas it is a variable for table name I have changed/ edited the question now

@VikasSharma I have added the entire stack trace please let me know if it helps
